# SonarQube: SQL Server 2014 Compatibility Mode

Tags: sql-server, sonarqube, compatibility, sonarqube-ops

Will SonarQube support its database hosted by SQL Server 2016 with database compatibility set to SQL Server 2014?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official support of SQLServer 2016 is planned for next Long Term Support version of series 6.x (see https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-8632). However it's supposed to already work with current version (6.2 at the time of writing).